# WordPress Themes using PHP 5.3

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it safe to create WordPress themes using PHP 5.3 for clients? Just a few months ago I started using 5.3 on my Hostgator server so I a not sure how widely used 5.3 is.

Comment: current version is `5.5`, Zend Community edition also includes a 5.3.x version. so its fairly stable.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't control the PHP version they run, probably not.

Even though PHP 5.3 has been out for a little over 4 years now, it takes a while for hosts to catch up.  Here's recent usage stats for 5.3

http://w3techs.com/technologies/details/pl-php/5.3/all